# Is it possible to implement the search functionality in a TreeGrid in smartGWT?

Tags: gwt, search, smartgwt, treegrid

Is it possible to replicate the search functionality found in ListGrid and implement it for a TreeGrid to find all the tree nodes which matches the search criteria?

Here is the one for the ListGrid:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_adaptive_filter_featured_category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TreeGrid** extends **ListGrid**. So whatever functionalities you're getting with **ListGrid**, are also available with **TreeGrid**. You can definitely have searching functionality in **TreeGrid** by these properties:

```
myTreeGrid.setShowFilterEditor(true);
myTreeGrid.setFilterOnKeypress(true);
```

But these functionalities will work only if you're using **DataSource** for generating the **TreeGrid** as per my knowledge.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: is it possible to generate data into a datasource if you are not using a database?

Comment: @Adel,Yes it's possible to fill the DataSource statically, without using database.

Comment: How do you populate a datasource with data manually without using an xml file?

Comment: @Adel,I can give you some code snippets for this but I'll not be able to post it in comment. Can you post this as a separate question?

Comment: here it is (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513148/how-do-you-populate-a-datasource-with-data-manually-without-using-an-xml-file)

Comment: @Adel, Not able to find post in the above link. Error msg: "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

Comment: I removed it because i figured it out myself. Thanks anyway :)